# Different execution under Windows and Linux with Go

Tags: go, execution

I created a very small game of number guessing in Go. The thing is, it executes differently under Windows and under Linux. By executing it on Ubuntu for example, everything works just fine. But when I try to start it under Windows, it compiles just fine but during execution when I enter something (for example 5) it prints me twice "Smaller than random num"or "Bigger than random num". I have no idea why it happens.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main () {
    var number int //declaration
    var tries int = 0
    random_number := random(1, 9) //gets random number
    for ; ;tries++ {
                //fmt.Printf("Enter your prediction: ")
                fmt.Scanf("%v",&number)
                if number == random_number {
                        break;
                } else if number<random_number{
                            fmt.Printf("Smaller than random num\n")
                } else {
                            fmt.Printf("Bigger than random num\n")
                }
         }
    fmt.Printf("You guessed correctly in %v tries",tries)

}

 func random(min, max int) int {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    return rand.Intn(max - min) + min
}
```

Comment: This is the execution under Windows 10:

4
Smaller than random num
Smaller than random num
5
Smaller than random num
Smaller than random num
7
Smaller than random num
Smaller than random num
9
Bigger than random num
Bigger than random num 
8
You guessed correctly in 8 tries

Comment: With Scanln it is an infinite loop, printing smaller than random num

Comment: And is there any error returned (is it a value `!= nil`?) Both [`Scanf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) and [`Scanln`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln) return the number of items processed and an error value that you should be checking.

Comment: No error is returned. Or at least not in the terminal (command prompt).

Comment: You assigned the two values returned by those functions and compared the error returned to ensure it's equal to `nil`, right? If it's not `nil`, there was a possible problem. See [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/4owK6-n31i)

Comment: Although the problem is solved, would you mind explaining the difference between null and nil?

Comment: Some languages call it "null". Go calls it "nil". That's all.

Comment: Thanks @Chrono Kitsune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines are different in Linux and Windows, and thus your program behaves differently.

See this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5391

To fix this, you can replace your Scanf with this (note the "\n" at the end):

```
fmt.Scanf("%v\n",&number)
```

Comment: @ChronoKitsune you're right - go version go1.8.1 windows/amd64,never would've thought of that, thanks.